# Как удалить в разделе "Виджеты" нижнюю часть сайта

Tags: wordpress

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как в разделе Виджеты, удалить "Нижнюю часть сайта 4"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> подскажите как в разделе Виджеты, удалить "Нижнюю часть сайта 4"?

Искать в теме код создания этой области. Удалять в [дочерней](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/). Как код создания так и вывод на сайте, если не проверяется его наличие.

**АПД**. Дочернюю тему рекомендую создавать при пом плагигинов. Напр https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/child-theme-configurator/ 
Это позволит перенести настройки родителя в дочку в большинстве тем (не во всех к сож, но во многих)

Comment: Что значит, удалять в дочерней?

Comment: Создать дочернюю тему. А что в неё и как переносить - зависит от того. как сделано в  родительской. По ссылке документация про дочки.

Comment: Вот на русском https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B но она устарела в способе создания дочки. Я в ответ добавил лучший способ. Он сделает всё легко и правильно.

Comment: Я просто только начал изучать Вордпресс, у меня после прочитанного просто мозг закипел.

Comment: Хорошо спасибо я почитаю

Comment: Тогда не обходимый минимум http://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/  а тут https://wp-kama.ru/functions ищешь функции  вхождением `sidebar` и изучаешь их. Желательно по кодексу. На вп-кама редко, но попадались ошибки